Using "certain" in "owing to his own certain skills"
I was tempting to rewrite the following phrase:

"owing to certain skills of him"

into:

"owing to certain skills of his own".

But then the following phrase hit me too:

"owing to his own certain skills".

For me, "owing to certain skills of his own" is idiomatic, but how about "owing to his own certain skills", is this also idiomatic?

his and certain in the cited context are both "determiners" - like the, those, some [specific skills]. English doesn't generally like multiple consecutive determiners, so it should either be ...owing to his [specific] skills OR ...owing to certain [specific] skills.

@FumbleFingers, very useful, thanks a lot!

Owing to certain skills of him is not idiomatic.
Owing to certain skills of his [own] is correct. It uses certain in the sense of something that is referred to without giving any specific information about it - that is, it doesn't say what the skills are.
Owing to his own certain skills doesn't mean the same; it implies that the skills are 'certain' in the sense of being sure or definite.

one concern remains: How do you know that "certain" in the third phrase means being sure? In fact, I'm onw thinking of another rephrasing: "Owing to his certain skills" (dropped "own"). With this version, "certain" is the same as "certain" in "owing to certain skills of his", I think?

Just because of the order of the words, which turns certain into an adjective instead of a determiner, as FumbleFingers explains.
